# Circle in pixel grid

Tags: python, numpy, graphics

Given the center `(x,y)` and radius `r`, how one can draw a circle `C((x,y),r)` in pixel grid using python? It is fine to assume that pixel grid is large enough.

Comment: Do you want to output a image file, or create an interactive application? If it's interactive, is it for data visualization, or a game?

Comment: @goncalopp I want a 2D array containing `0` and `1` such that `1` denote the location of circle.

Comment: Have a look into the [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm). Let us know if you struggle with an implementation detail.

Comment: @Falko Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want to get fancy & draw a smooth circle, take a look at [Fast, Antialiased Circles and Ellipses from Xiaolin Wu’s concepts](https://yellowsplash.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/fast-antialiased-circles-and-ellipses-from-xiaolin-wus-concepts/). The code on that site is in Pascal, but it doesn't look _too_ hard to translate to Python. FWIW, Wu's line algorithm is the standard for drawing antialiased lines; his circle algorithm is less well-known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the RosettaCode [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) in Python

```
def circle(self, x0, y0, radius, colour=black):
    f = 1 - radius
    ddf_x = 1
    ddf_y = -2 * radius
    x = 0
    y = radius
    self.set(x0, y0 + radius, colour)
    self.set(x0, y0 - radius, colour)
    self.set(x0 + radius, y0, colour)
    self.set(x0 - radius, y0, colour)

    while x < y:
      if f >= 0: 
        y -= 1
        ddf_y += 2
        f += ddf_y
        x += 1
        ddf_x += 2
        f += ddf_x    
        self.set(x0 + x, y0 + y, colour)
        self.set(x0 - x, y0 + y, colour)
        self.set(x0 + x, y0 - y, colour)
        self.set(x0 - x, y0 - y, colour)
        self.set(x0 + y, y0 + x, colour)
        self.set(x0 - y, y0 + x, colour)
        self.set(x0 + y, y0 - x, colour)
        self.set(x0 - y, y0 - x, colour)
        Bitmap.circle = circle

        bitmap = Bitmap(25,25)
        bitmap.circle(x0=12, y0=12, radius=12)
        bitmap.chardisplay()
```

Comment: It's better to make the link text a little more meaningful to guard against link rot. Eg "Here's the RosettaCode [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#Python) in Python". True, rosettacode is a rather stable site, but you never know... and it's a good habit to get into on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the comment. I will fix it.

Comment: What if I would like to implement this on matplotlib?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to *get things done* (as opposed to learning raster graphics algorithms), simply use [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
image = Image.new('1', (10, 10)) #create new image, 10x10 pixels, 1 bit per pixel
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse((2, 2, 8, 8), outline ='white')
print list(image.getdata())
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The range is 0..255 because Pillow stores a byte-per-pixel even for a 1-bit-per-pixel image (as its more efficient).

If you want the range on 0..1, you can then divide by 255:

```
[x/255 for x in image.getdata()]
```